# Mensagem de cunho religioso

Tags: debate

Acabei de fazer uma edição de primeira publicação que continha a seguinte frase:

> Deus abençoe você! Ele é bom o tempo todo.

Removi pois se trata de uma mensagem de cunho religioso que nada tem a ver com o conteúdo do site.

Além disso, entendo que esse tipo de mensagem pode incomodar pessoas que possuem outras crenças. Por outro lado, também entendo que remover a mensagem pode incomodar o autor da resposta na sua crença.

Como achei um assunto delicado, gostaria de debater como proceder a respeito.

Comment: Na minha opinião se uma parte da pergunta ou resposta, não é essencial nem diz respeito ao que é proposto no site. Ela pode ser removida/editada contando que essa parte não comprometa a integridade da pergunta ou da resposta. Quanto as polêmicas que pode gerar, bom em relação a isso a gente espera que os usuários da nossa comunidade usem de bom senso para julgar e realizar as edições.

Comment: @CaiqueRomero acho que podia formular uma resposta.

Comment: Ainda complementa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: Portanto não cabe debater isso em específico, é inadequado ter conteúdo que não faça parte da pergunta ou resposta. Ponto.